# Why does data-url come back undefined after being set?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Anyone know why I can't retrieve my variable immediately after I set it here? Assigning it to a data-url attribute of an anchor.

```
    var myUrl = 'http://www.google.com/';

    alert('set: ' + myUrl);

    $("#tweet-link").attr('data-url', myUrl);

    alert('get: ' + $("#tweet-link").attr('data-url')); // 'get: undefined'
```

Comment: If you look at what the html looks like after setting that, I think you'll find that it's likely not being enclosed by quotes. I run into this all the time.

Comment: This code works for me just fine. Is your code in a `$(document).ready()` callback?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/sX2p2/.. Working here

Comment: Do you have an element with id `tweet-link`? jQuery doesn't complain about that. Try alerting the `.length` of the collection

Comment: If you want to use data attributes with jQuery use `.data('url', myUrl)` and `.data('url')` instead of `attr`.

Comment: Just to remind that `.data('url')` will return the value of attribue 'data-url' ... but setting it with `.data('url', value)` will not add an attribute ... this is in case attribute should be created ... using `.data()` is preferable If you don't mind that attribute won't be added. Note that this method currently does not provide cross-platform support for setting data on XML documents, as Internet Explorer does not allow data to be attached via expando properties.

Answer (score 1):

All the possible reasons are already mentioned as comments here: Not executed on `$(document).ready()` or the `id` is wrong or the tag doesn't exist at all.

When DOM structure is not ready jQuery will not save the data, because element still doesn't exists. jQuery will not show error, because will assume that no item is selected.

```
$(function() {
  ...your code here...
});
```

Just to add that data could be get also using `$("#tweet-link").data('url')`.

No need of voting ... just compacting already done comments in an answer.

Comment: Code is inside a document.ready, id is correct and exists, and I still get undefined. Happens when I use `.data('url', myUrl)`, and `.data('url')`

Comment: There is a note in the docs that .data() has no full cross browser compatability for IE, but it works in the versions I tested. may be earlier versions 6,7 but I don't have them. In competability mode - works. IE tester - ver.6 and 7 - works too.